I sent a post request, but I keep getting a null value
i send this data
i send this data
but it always get null
but it always get null
I want to comment on each movie
I don't know where the problem is
CommentController
It's the part where you get it through post-mapping and hand it over to service
I couldn't get movie_Id, so I got a movie_Id for the variable id
@PostMapping("/search/{title}/comments")
public ResponseEntity<CommentDto> addComment(@PathVariable String title,@RequestBody CommentDto dto) {
            

log.info("received Dto{}",dto.toString());

    int id= moviesSearchService.findByTitletoId(title);
    CommentDto commentDto=commentService.create(id,dto);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(commentDto);
}

When I look at the log, it says that the request body itself is null
like this

2024-05-05T00:14:57.173+09:00  INFO 1880 --- [softwareEngBE] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.s.controller.CommentApiController    : received DtoCommentDto(id=0, movieId=0, rating=0, comment=null)

CommentService
It's a processing process of storing in the Repository, I don't think there's no problem.
public CommentDto create(int id, CommentDto dto) {
Movies movies = moviesRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalArgumentException("No exist movie"));



Comment comment=Comment.createComment(dto,movies);

Comment created=commentRepository.save(comment);
return CommentDto.createCommentDto(created);
}

CommentDto
I can't find a lot of questions, but I can't find it.I put it well in the camelCase
public class CommentDto {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private long id;

    @JsonProperty("movie_Id")
    private int movieId;

    @JsonProperty("rating")
    private int rating;

    @JsonProperty("comment")
    private String comment;


    public static CommentDto createCommentDto(Comment comment) {
        return new CommentDto(
                comment.getId(),
                comment.getMovies().getMovie_Id(),
                comment.getRating(),
                comment.getComment()
        );
    }
}

Comment, Movies Entity
It's my first time writing a code using fk and I think there might be a problem here as well
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="movie_Id")
    private Movies movies;

    @Column
    private int rating;
    @Column
    private String comment;

    public static Comment createComment(CommentDto dto,Movies movies){
        return new Comment(
                dto.getId(),
                movies,
                dto.getRating(),
                dto.getComment()
        );
    }

}

public class Movies {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int movie_Id;
    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String genres;

    public static Movies createMovies(MoviesDto dto){
        return new Movies(dto.getMovie_Id(), dto.getTitle(), dto.getGenres());
    }
}

CommentRepository
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment,Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "Select * " +
            "from comment " +
            "where movie_Id = :id",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Comment> findByMovieId(int id);
}

I want to create the value I sent you, not null

CommentDto don't have any getters or setters.

i use @getter ,@setter

Can you provide a reproductible example on github or something?

Too much code, too many images of text. Please check [ask] and add a [mcve]. Do not just link to your github.

@antoine.lange Thanks guys this is my github  github.com/2024cinematch/CineMatch_BE/tree/TC_9 problem in comment parts!!

@Robert  there is my git adress!

Dude, please check [ask]. Nobody wants to dig through your whole repository. You need to provide a [mcve]. Links can break, and linked content can change, especially on github, which makes the question unusable for others with similar problems. You'll get more out of stackoverflow when you follow its rules.

You are receiving null values in your CommentDto object because you are not using the right annotation @RequestBody in your controller. You are using an annotation from swagger instead of spring. You have to change the import line in CommentApiController from import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody to the one from Spring import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody.
Hope it helps!

How on earth did you guess that from the question? The code snippts do not even show the imports

The questionner put a link to GitHub with a minimal reproductible example in one of the comments
